how does python determine encodings under different circumstances?
I have a python script that runs on a windows machine and looks like this:
print(f"Current encoding: {sys.stdout.encoding}")
print(some_randomized_chars)

and I run it in different ways using pycharm.
My confusion is about the way it behaves when it comes to encodings.
When I run it "normally", i.e., Pycharm's "Run" or going to pycharm's terminal (powershell) and running
python producer.py

I get
Current encoding: utf-8

And everything get printed to the terminal, including some "gibberish" chars on occasion, which is fine. However, when trying to pipe it
python producer.py > test.txt

it creates a file whose 1st line is
Current encoding: cp1252

but sometimes I get this error thrown in the terminal after some successful writes:
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9e' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>

Lastly, I would expect the encoding of the created test.txt to be cp1252 (ANSI latin), but when I open it in a text editor, it shows it's utf-16 LE.
So my confusion here sums up to these questions:
-Why does python print "utf-8" as the current encoding when running normally?
-Why does it then switch to "cp1252" when running it with piping, and why does it sometimes crash?
-If the encoding in the latter case is ANSI, why does it show utf-16 LE on the file itself?
Thank you

The distinction between console output and pipe output is explained in the docs. The exception indicates that some character in a string couldn't be encoded in "cp1252".

There are two distinct environments to consider: (a) Python, whose behavior depends on whether output is sent to the console (terminal) - in which case there is full Unicode support - or whether output is captured (sent through a pipeline, redirected to a file) - in which case the system's active legacy ANSI code page applies.
(b) PowerShell, which with > up to v7.3 first decodes Python's output based on the encoding stored in [Console]::OutputEncoding] and then re-encodes the resulting text based on >'s default output encoding. See the linked duplicate for details.
